# Async/Await returning promise before running function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to map a function within an async route, but `res.send` is firing before the function and returning a promise. I've tried rearranging where I am calling async and await, but haven't had any luck getting it to work so far.

route

```
router.post('/garageOrders', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let {month} = req.body
    try {
        const LocationMonth = await Orders.distinct("location", {"date" : {$regex : ".*Apr.*"}});
        const LocationObj = LocationMonth.map((item) => calcTotals(item));
        console.log(LocationObj);
        res.send(LocationObj);
    } catch {
        res.status(400).send("No Garages Found");
    }
})
```

calcTotal function

```
const calcTotals = async (item) => {
    let newTotal = 0;
    let newQuantity = 0;
    await Orders.find({ $and: [{"date" : {$regex : ".*Apr.*"}}, {location: item}]})
        .then(resp => {
            resp.forEach((order) => {
                newTotal = order.total + newTotal;
                newQuantity = newQuantity + 1;
            })
            console.log(item.name);
            console.log(newTotal);
            console.log(newQuantity);
            console.log('///////////////////////////////////////');
        })
    return {
        name: item.name,
        total: newTotal,
        quantity: newQuantity
    }
}
```

console.log (data is calculating correctly, but is not being returned before the promise.)

```
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
Miranova
85
1
///////////////////////////////////////
75 East Main Street
125
1
///////////////////////////////////////
Bicentennial Lot
125
1
///////////////////////////////////////
#722 South High Garage
410
2
///////////////////////////////////////
107 Garage
240
2
///////////////////////////////////////
City of Columbus Parking Garage
480
4
///////////////////////////////////////
SHERATON HOTEL VALET - COLUMBUS
560
5
///////////////////////////////////////
LEVEQUE GARAGE
120
1
///////////////////////////////////////
Crazy Joes Parking Garage
190
1
///////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: map will return promises, you gotta await them. Check `Promise.all`.

Comment: `const LocationObj = await Promise.all(LocationMonth.map((item) => calcTotals(item)));`

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!